# StackOverflowError with Recursion

Tags: java, exception, recursion, compiler-errors, stack-overflow

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? It is really bugging me. What I am trying to do is find the sum of the expression 2^k +1 as k ranges from 1 through n.

```
import java.util.*;

public class mySums
{
private static double n;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    recurSum(4);
    System.out.println();
}

/*  public static void iterativeSum (int num)
{

}
*/
public static double recurSum (double num)
{
    if (n==1){
      return 1;}
    else {
      return (Math.pow(2.0, n) +1) + recurSum(n-1);}
}
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You use `recurSum(n-1)`, but `recurSum` is passed the variable `num`, not `n`. I don't think that's what you want to do, is it?

Comment: Hint : n is static, its value doesnt change thus your recursion is infinite. Use something non-static

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are using `n` instead of `num` in your `recurSum`. `n` is a static variable that never changes; you should remove it. `num`, on the other hand, is a parameter that you pass to `recurSum`; its value decreases as you go down the levels of recursive invocations, eventually hitting `1` and letting you exit:

```
public static double recurSum (double num) {
    if (num==1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (Math.pow(2.0, num) +1) + recurSum(num-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the reason?  I'm thinking it shouldn't even compile at all if that were the case, no?  Ah nvm just noticed n is static.

Comment: @Kiwi Why not? `n` is a legitimate `static` variable, it's there for all static methods to access, so the compiler happily compiles this into something that guarantees stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Never use "==" with double because of precision problems, so your recursion is never ending.

Change it to

```
if (n <= 1)
```

Also I just noticed that the function takes an argument "num" so "n" is undefined in the function, but I'm assuming that's just a typo here.

Comment: The `==` operator is a good advice but not the center of the problem.

Comment: Ah yeah just noticed n is static.